# must install package each time I restart emacs?

Tags: emacs, package-management

On emacs, I must do M-x package install for the package google-translate 
each time I restart emacs, is this normal? (new to emacs)

Comment: Your answer only expects a "yes" or a "no", which wouldn't do anyone any good.  Please give more details to explain what behavior you see and what behavior you want.

Comment: Aha, yes currently I must do package-install google-translate every time I start Emacs. I would prefer this to load automatically on Emacs startup !

Comment: Who/what forces you to `M-x package-install` every time?